# slow internet Problem on kubuntu 9.10 AMD x64

Tags: 64-bit, internet, ubuntu-9.10, performance, kubuntu

I've recently installed kubuntu 9.10 AMD x64, on an HP 6830s. The installation went smoothly, with only one problem: when I try to use the internet, it's incredibly slow. I couldn't install Firefox or anything that requires the internet. I have tried most of the solutions I found through Google, but none of them solves the problem.

What can I do?

Comment: what does `ip -statistics l` say? (after experiencing slow internet)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking if IPv6 is enabled as a first step. Under the System menu, open Network Connections, select your interface, click Edit, click the IPv6 tab and make sure that Ignored is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does not seem to be a problem of (K)Ubuntu, but of your router or ISP (see [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/417757) for a looong bug report). Therefore, I advise you to **not** disable IPv6. While this might help in short term, he problem will probably hunt you down again in one or two years when IPv6 takes over from IPv4.

The first thing you **should** try is updating your router's firmware. This completely solved the problem for me (and others). If this doesn't help, you should bug either your ISP or the router's manufacturer until they fix things.